# My floating Divs don't line up

Tags: css, html, css-float, position, block

I am trying to make a nice CSS menu bar. The problem is no matter if each button is in it's own  element or if it is in a

element, either way it always does this funny stepping thing:

if you go to www.adversign.co.za/steps.jpg

I have tried float:left; i have tried it with clear:both; i have tried it with display:inline-block; as well as display:block;
But nothing that i do seems to align the tops of the div's at the same height.

Please can someone help.
my code is like this:

```
<div id="list">
<li><a href="index.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#list a { 
float:left; 
display: inline; 
list-style:none; 
background:url(images/home1.png) no-repeat; 
background-position:top left; 
width:104px; 
height:109px; 
font-size:1px; 
color:#000; 
text-decoration:none; 
margin-left:0px;
} 
#list a:hover{ 
background:url(images/home2.png) no-repeat; 
text-decoration:none;
```

Comment: hard to help if you don't show html + css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ul, with float:left on the li elements

http://jsfiddle.net/pB7rt/2/

Comment: that worked. but what doesn't help is that i wanted the div's to align... but for what i want to do it is fine for now

Answer (score 2):

Try display:inline-block;

http://jsfiddle.net/VkHVd/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://css-tricks.com/prevent-menu-stepdown/

You say you've tried `display: inline-block;` and `display: block;`

But not `display: inline;`

Comment: check with firebug or similar to make sure you aren't overriding it down the track, also what browser are you using?

Comment: the only other solution I can suggest without seeing the CSS is to comment out all css affecting the menu, then bring code back in until it plays up again, starting with float:left; and list-style: none;

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is wrong. You have

```
<div id="list">
<li><a href="index.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
</div>
```

instead of

```
<ul id="list">
<li><a href="index.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
```

btw: you can delete display: inline, because float: left makes it block anyway.

Here is jsfiddle with your version: [Your version](http://jsfiddle.net/RubQe/)
And here is jsfiddle with ul instead of div: [Correct version](http://jsfiddle.net/RubQe/1/)

Comment: @mtk I managed to solve it, the reason why I didn't see error was @ before file_put_contents and the errror was typo in a class name

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the best way to do it on my own and totally forgot that i asked this question on this forum.

```
<ul id="list">
<li><a href="index.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is the way i had the HTML, i just typed it wrong in the question.

I know now to do my CSS like this

```
ul#list li {
   float:left;
...etc.
}
```

and then style the button

```
ul#list li a {
display:block;
...etc
}
```

with the hover on the li:

```
ul#list li:hover a {
}
```